# Why am I getting empty result by using regex in sql?

Tags: sql, regex

There is a column named as **keyword** of the product table.

```
+---------+
| keyword |
+---------+
| dump    |
| dump2   |
| dump4   |
| dump5   |
| pro     |
+---------+
```

I am fetching those results from product table by using **regex** whose **keyword** containing the string **du** anywhere.
I used `select * from products where keyword LIKE '%[du]%';`
but it is returning empty set.
What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: which sql engine are you using?

Comment: I think you're mixing the concepts here. `[du]` is looking for a single character, either `d` or `u`; in that case, you don't need those `%` at all. Why can't you use just a normal `LIKE` search - `WHERE keyword LIKE '%du%'`?

Comment: @zealous Server version: 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Comment: @raina77ow returning empty set by using `keyword LIKE '[du]';` and I want to grab those results by using **regex** only

Comment: If you want to use *regex*, use *regex* and not plain `LIKE`. And the statement you need to use depends on the flavor of SQL used (which should be added to your question as tag btw).

Comment: @raina77ow I used `keyword REGEXP '[du]'` and it works but If I want to grab the negation I used `keyword REGEXP '[^du]'` then why it is returning all five rows ?

Comment: Because that's not how negated character class works. With `[^du]` you ask "is there any character **that's not either d or u** (in that column)?" Well, it is there for all the lines you mentioned.

Comment: The proper solution in this case would be just negating the whole result of REGEXP predicate: `where keyword NOT REGEXP 'du'`.

Comment: ok I got it....

Comment: Btw, the syntax you used is SQL Server's T-SQL, which has some extensions to Standard SQL, but no functonality supporting RegEx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *must* use regex, you can just use `du` as the regex; that will match the string `du` anywhere in the keyword:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE keyword REGEXP 'du'
```

Output:

```
keyword
dump
dump2
dump4
dump5
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8oUy9wbjDdhnaDodWT26rs/0)